# Bootstrap carousel not working, cannot find reason why

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootstrap carousel but the images and captions are showing on top of one another. I have been looking at my code for an hour and cannot find the problem.

I have tried using a CDN for bootstrap and the javascript files and it was not working then either, I am using a local version. Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Bootstrap links

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Gemma Seabourne Photography</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Gemma Seabourne Photography">
  <meta name="author" content="CJ-Design">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

...

```
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

Carousel:

```
<section class="slider-menu">
        <!--Image slider & aside of the menu buttons-->
        <aside class="side-menu">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">Book</a>
          <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">Portfolio</a>
          <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">What to expect</a>
          <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">Services</a>
        </aside>

        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Carousel indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="img/placeholder-img.jpg" alt="First Slide">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>First slide label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/placeholder-img.jpg" alt="First Slide">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                        <p>Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/placeholder-img.jpg" alt="First Slide">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna vel...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Carousel nav -->
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

      </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code snippet. Connected with the aside menu as well.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="slider-menu">
  <!--Image slider & aside of the menu buttons-->
  <aside class="side-menu">
    <a href="#" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">Book</a>
    <a href="#" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">What to expect</a>
    <a href="#" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">Services</a>
  </aside>

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://www.fp.utm.my/projek/psm/juzclick/images/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" alt="First Slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>First slide label</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.fp.utm.my/projek/psm/juzclick/images/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" alt="First Slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Second slide label</h3>
          <p>Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.fp.utm.my/projek/psm/juzclick/images/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" alt="First Slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Third slide label</h3>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna vel...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.fp.utm.my/projek/psm/juzclick/images/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" alt="First Slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Fourth slide label</h3>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna vel...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
  </div>

</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked! Seems I must have had something wrong linking my bootstrap and jquery files :)

Comment: great. check now. I have linked it with the aside menu. Tick the answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be something missing in your Bootstrap files because your code looks good. Heres a fiddle if it helps. I also added some actual placeholder images instead of the broken images to make sure it is working.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="First Slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>First slide label</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="First Slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                <p>Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x150" alt="First Slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna vel...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

[Working Carousel](https://jsfiddle.net/npshwfjh/)